# How to define a function whose parameter have a list with default-value

Tags: function-construction

As we know,we can define a function with default-value like this:

```
fun1[x_, n_: 1, a_: 2, b_: 3] := x + n + a + b
```

> In[6]:= fun1[4]
>
> Out[6]= 10

But in my case I hope the `a` and `b` in a list,So I define it like:

```
fun2[x_, n_: 1, {a_: 2, b_: 3}] := x + n + a + b
```

> In[8]:= fun2[5]
>
> Out[8]= fun2[5]

It's failure.And I have a try this,it is failue too:

```
fun3[x_, n_: 1, l_List: {a_: 2, b_: 3}] := x + n + a + b
```

It have a strange result:

> In[16]:= fun3[5]
>
> Out[16]= 6 + a + b

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT 03 / 02 / 2018**

Please note that starting with version 11.2, the behavior of the pattern-matcher was changed so that the solution below no longer works. The problem with the solution below is that it makes it possible for a variable pointing at entire pattern, to get bound to something else than the expression where inner pattern variables get substituted with their default values. That is inconsistent, and that is one reason why the behavior of the pattern matcher has been modified.

**--------------------------**

The problem here is that the pattern you used, requires a `List` as a last argument in all cases. A possible workaround will be, for example:

```
ClearAll[fun2];
fun2[x_, n_: 1, p : {a_: 2, b_: 3} : {}] := x + n + a + b
```

So that

```
fun2[5]
fun2[5, 2, {1}]
fun2[5, 10, {1, 2}]

(*
  11

  11

  18
*)
```

Comment: +Infinity.Very interesting.

Comment: When I run this function in my Mathematica 11.2, `fun2[5]` gives `6`. But when I run it in Mathematica 11.1.1 in another computer, `fun2[5]` gives `11`. What is wrong?

Comment: @renphysics I have discussed this with colleagues. Apparently, the current behavior (returning 6) is correct, while the one I used above, while convenient, is not. The main point is this: if `p` becomes an empty list by default, that should mean that both `a` and `b` become `Sequence[]` ("nothing"), and then when used in `Plus`, they don't contribute. The change has indeed been introduced after 11.1

Comment: @renphysics  What the pattern language really lacks here is the primitive like `AutomaticDefault`, so that we could have `fun2[x_, n_: 1, p : {a_: 2, b_: 3} : AutomaticDefault] := x + n + a + b`, which would mean that the value of `p` is determined from the values of inner constituents (bound pattern variables). In this case, it would result in `p` being bound to `{2, 3}` and `fun2[5]` returning `11`, as we want it here.

Answer (score 4):

Give a default value to the *list* instead:

```
fun2[x_, n_: 1, a_List: {2, 3}] := x + n + Plus@@a
fun2[10]
(* 16 *)
```

Comment: Thanks your answer.you almost solve my problem.But there a blemish still that the `2` and `3` have not its name.Of course we can use `a[[1]]` or `a[[2]]` to extract its value.Could you help me name the default-value `2` as `a` and the `3` as `b` in the `fun2`?

Comment: Fool me long time.And look forward to your response.As your answer ,your `fun2` work well.Like `fun2[1, 4, {7, 8}]` will give a right result.But when I built a new function.`fun[a_, l_list: {2, 3}] := a + Plus @@ l`.The `fun[1, {4, 5}]` will give up to compute.

Comment: @yode. You need to capitalize `list` in the function definition: `fun[a_, l_List: {2, 3}] := a + Plus @@ l` works.

Comment: God~The typo harm me deeply.

Answer (score 3):

Other method is to add two definitions as follows:

```
ClearAll[fun2];
fun2[x_, n_: 1, {a_: 2, b_: 3}] := x + n + a + b
fun2[x_, n_: 1, a_: 2, b_: 3] := x + n + a + b

fun2[5]
fun2[5, 2]
fun2[5, 2, {1}]
fun2[5, 10, {1, 2}]
(*
  11
  12
  11
  18
*)
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation

what about this effect???

Comment: @yode, This is a pattern matching where `fun2[5]` and `fun2[5, 2]` match the definition `fun2[x_, n_: 1, a_: 2, b_: 3]` and the evaluation happens.  `fun2[5, 2, {1}]` and `fun2[5, 10, {1, 2}]` match `fun2[x_, n_: 1, {a_: 2, b_: 3}]` and the evaluation happens also.

Answer (score 3):

You can also go for something as simple as function overloading:

```
f[x_, n_:1] := f[x, n, {2, 3}];
f[x_, n_, {a_, b_}] := x + n + a + b;
```